# Calling a custom method in LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, datacontext

I have a query like this:

```
 var q = 
        from u in db.User
        select new
        {
            userId = u.UserId,
            userName = o.Name,
            userAvatar = o.AvatarCode
        };
```

Then, I have to transform *AvatarCode* to *AvatarPath* using custom static method *Image.GetPath*.

It's possible to make this in the following way:

```
 var q = 
        (from u in db.User
        select new
        {
            userId = u.UserId,
            userName = o.Name,
            userAvatar = o.AvatarCode
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(new
        {
            userId = u.UserId,
            userName = o.Name,
            userAvatar = Image.GetPath(o.AvatarCode)
        };
```

But if the number of object fields is large then it's an overkill to duplicate all fields in the second *Select*.

**Are there any alternatives?**

For example, some approach to mark methods that should be executed after query execution:

```
 var q = 
        from u in db.User
        select new
        {
            userId = u.UserId,
            userName = o.Name,
            userAvatar = Linq.ExecuteLater(Image.GetPath(o.AvatarCode))
        };
```

Comment: Your code example looks not logic. 1) What is `o` in your first `select`? 2) Why you repeating referencing to `u` and `o` in the second `Select` and even without reference to current element of collection. So your second select should be like this: `Select(i => new { userId = i.userId })` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any such method but if the problem is only number of fields which must be specified again in the second select you can do something like this:

```
var q = 
    (from u in db.User
    select new
    {
        userId = u.UserId,
        userName = u.Name,
        userAvatar = u.AvatarCode
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(u => new
    {
        User = u,
        Path = Image.GetPath(u.AvatarCode)
    });
```