# Calling custom (formatting) method on LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF 4.1 and I'm trying to enumerate a company list for a grid. I have two options in the current project: select all companies from the DbContext (`Entities`) and load them into an object from a non-anonymous type (let's say `EmpresaGrid`) or select all companies into anonymous type objects with the same structure like `Empresa` (which is the entity I'm selecting from).

The first option (creating a model class for that) would require a little more work, but can be, eventually, more readable. Still, I'm not sure about that. The second option is what I'm using right now.

So, **first question**: it's better to create a model class only for displaying data or use anonymous type? Doing a direct select is out of question: a `SELECT *` is too big and that might make everything damn slow (I guess). So selection into another type creates a custom query with only the needed fields.

Using the second option (anonymous type), I have this code (simplified version):

```
public static IEnumerable<object> Grid()
{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    var empresas = db.Empresas
        .Select(e => new
        {
            Cgc = e.Cgc, // PK
            (...)
            Address = new
            {
                AddressLine = e.EnderecoSede.AddressLine,
                (...)
            }
        },
        Contato = e.Contato,
        (...)
    })
    .ToList();

    return empresas;
}
```

The anonymous type I'm creating has around 40 lines of code, so it's kinda big, but it recreates part of the `Empresa` class struct (since the grid is waiting for a `Empresa` object). Anyway, I have a problem with the data format. For example, I would like to format the `Cgc` property using a custom string format. I have a public method for this, `FormataCgc`. This method receives a string and returns it formatted using some internal conditions.

So, my problem is how to that. For example, I have tried this:

```
var empresas = db.Empresas
    .Select(e => new
    {
        Cgc = FormataCgc(e.Cgc),
    }
```

But that doesn't work because FormataCgc cannot be translated into SQL (and I don't want to convert it). I also tried this:

```
var empresas = db.Empresas
    .Select(e => new
    {
        (...)
    }
    .ToList();

foreach (var e in empresas) {
    e.Cgc = FormataCgc(e.Cgc);
}
```

But it cannot be done since anonymous types have only read-only properties.

So, my **second question** is: how exactly can I do that? I need to change the data after selecting it, but using anonymous types? I've done a little research, and the best thing I've found was this: [Calling a custom method in LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086574/calling-a-custom-method-in-linq-query). In that solution, Ladislav suggested doing a second select from the IEnumerable, but since the grid is excepting `Empresa` I cannot do that (I need to change or add properties, not encapsulate them).

I'm not sure if I was clear enough, but feel free to ask any questions. Also, the grid I'm currently using is a Telerik ASP.NET MVC Grid, which receives a IEnumerable (where T is a class) as model data and them iterates each object, doing its magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already converting this into an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can do the custom formatting as you stream the results in the client.  Do your db.Select, and then convert to the appropriate format afterwards, ie:

```
var empresas = db.Empresas
    .Select(e => new
    {
        (...)
    })
    .ToList();

foreach (var e in empresas) {
    yield return new {
       Cgc = FormataCgc(e.Cgc),
       // Copy other properties here, as needed...
    };
}
```

That being said, I'd personally recommend making a custom class, and not return an anonymous type.  Your conversion would then be:

```
foreach (var e in empresas) {
    yield return new YourClass(FormataCgc(e.Cgc), ...); // Construct as needed
}
```

This will dramatically improve the usability of this method, as you will have proper, named access to your properties *from the caller of the method*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution to both of your questions is to create a model class. Sure it is a little bit more work up front, but it will allow you greater flexibility in the long run. Your custom model class can then handle the formatting for you.

```
public class EmpresaGridModel
{
    public string Cgc { get; set; }

    public string CgcFormatted 
    {
        return FormataCgc(this.Cgc);
    }

    //properties for the other fields will have to be created as well obviously
}
```

Your telerik grid can then bind directly to the CgcFormatted property